# looping Unique values - nodejs

Tags: javascript

How can I fix: **code 2** output password is the same?

And why the **code 2** password is the same?

**code 1**:

```
var arr = [
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' },
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' },
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' },
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' },
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' },
    { email: '', role: 'normal', password: '' }
]

arr.forEach(o => { o.password = Math.random() })

output: [{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.16326031488429638 },
{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.4941354999549721 },
{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.6802056630925 },
{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.5038916232454755 },
{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.5232000715886489 },
{ email: '', role: 'normal', password: 0.1599782533612224 }]
```

**code 2**:

```
var obj = {
    email: '1',
    role: 'normal',
    password: ''
}, array = []

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    array.push(function () {
        obj.password = Math.random()
        return obj
    })
}
```

**Output**:

> [{ email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 },
>
> { email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 },
>
> { email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 },
>
> { email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 },
>
> { email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 },
>
> { email: '1', role: 'normal', password: 0.4311454570811686 }]

Comment: Please make an attempt to make this question legible. I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: waiting ...................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you keep pushing the same object into the array over and over. So technically you end up with just the one object with several references. Instead try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    array.push(Object.assign({}, obj, {password: Math.random()}));
}
```

Using Object.assign() to "clone" the object.

Comment: can you gave me some url about this.

Comment: Sure, this [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is great.